# Latest version of ctags

Tags: ctags, exuberant-ctags

Where is developed `exuberant ctags`? I [found](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) that latest version is [5.8](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ctags/files/) but in my system there is already version `5.9`.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not write where you got your version "5.9" from. Are you using Debian, Ubuntu or some other Debian derivative?

Debian actually packages an unreleased version. On my system, ctags-exuberant reports its version as `Exuberant Ctags 5.9~svn20110310` - meaning it is compiled directly from the SVN repository as it was on 2011-03-10.

This is noted in the Debian changelog of the package ( /usr/share/doc/exuberant-ctags/changelog.Debian.gz ):

```
exuberant-ctags (1:5.9~svn20110310-1) unstable; urgency=low

  * New upstream release snapshot (thanks, Daniel Hahler; LP: #732860).
```

"LP: #732860" refers to [Launchpad bug #732860](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/exuberant-ctags/+bug/732860), where the new release is discussed.

So sourceforge.net is still the place to go for ctags development, it's just that they have not made a release for a long time.

Comment: Thanks, I have the same version as you in `Lubuntu`. So, the development is on `launchpad` and main releases are sent to `sourceforge`? Is [this](https://code.launchpad.net/exuberant-ctags) the hot place where development takes place?

Comment: @xralf: No, the page https://code.launchpad.net/exuberant-ctags you link to only contains a copy of the code from sourceforge.net. The main repository is apparently on Sourceforge, namely https://ctags.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/ctags/trunk/ ; the last checkin there was on 2011-12-10.

Comment: And BTW, you might want to consider `cscope` instead of ctags. I used ctags myself, but switched to cscope because results were better. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289381/ctags-chokes-on-source-file-with-unbalanced-braces-due-to-ifdef